# Post параметры в yii через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, yii, yii2

вызываю ajax в своем скрипте с помощью jquery. Для этого создал отдельный контролллер (AjaxController) и в нем некий метод actionRequest. jQueryпередает туда post запрос:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: location.origin + '/ajax/request',
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'params': params},//масив
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {result = data}
});
```

в самом скрипте уже такой код:

```
$params = Yii::$app->request->get('params')
echo $params;
```

Проблемма в том, что post -запросы доходить до сервера нехотят. get идет нормально, а меняю на post- ничего не приходит. При чем делаю запрос к своему скрипту (просто пхп скрипт не привязаный к движку))- все идет нормально....

p.s. не знаю пока как все это трактовать. в код экшэна заношу следующие действия:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$file = fopen($root . '/text.txt', 'w');
fwrite($file, '1');
fclose($file);
```

Если передаю get-запрос то файл в корне сайта создаеться. если передаю post то даже файл создаваться не хочет. Такое ощущение что он прерываеться гдето на много раньше и при передачи post запроса даже код мой не выполняет...

Comment: Где null выводит? в `success`? а в `params` вы уверены что что-то передается?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, изменил вопрос всоответствие с новой информацией.

Comment: А при изменении в `ajax` на `type: 'POST',` вы не забываете в `php` тоже написать пост? `Yii::$app->request->` **post** `('params')` . Покажите еще свой массив `params` на всякий случай

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, разумееться не забыл. и массив убрал- теперь передаю там только число 32. Ставлю get- все работает. потом меняю на post - в js и в php,больше ничего не делаю -работать перестает. Это если отправляю контролеру. еслиже обращаюсь к собственному php-скрипту то все с таким кодом передаеться нормально. причем пробывал и методы класса и масив $_POSt,ничего не меняеться. даже чистый yii ставил- тоже самое.

Comment: Попробуйте в логах посмотреть, что говорится, если говорится.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в логах пусто если те что нужно смотрел (apache и php) у yii логов не нашел. функция log() возвращает undefined.. попробовал весь код из контролера убрать и оставить только получение $_post и передачу результата, а к скрипту обратился из js на прямую -все получилось. а если скрипт оформлен как контролер - post параметры не принемаются....

еще вот попробовал передавать обратно другую строку(не сам параметр post) - в get все работает, а в post даже возвращать обратно ничего не хочет..

Comment: еще подправил вопрос в соответствие с новыми данными...

Answer (score 1):

Используйте:

```
$id = Yii::app()->request->getPost('id');     // Только post
$id = Yii::app()->request->getParam('id');    // Для post и get
```